# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'values'

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, sharepoint-2013, chart.js

I have a graph i created from a SharePoint list and it works in Chrome but does not work in IE 11. When i went to debug in IE 11 and I get the error `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'values'`. I am fairly new to JavaScript.

Can anybody tell me what may be a fix or what I am missing

I am using chart.js and ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/carm/Shared%20Documents/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/carm/Shared%20Documents/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajax({
        url: "/sites/carm/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ATO%20Conditions')/items?$select=ID,Title,m4gs&$top=5000",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function(data) {

            if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
                var inactiveSet = {};
                var activeSet = {};
                var otherSet = {};
                var totalActive = 0;
                var totalInActive = 0;
                var totalOther = 0;
                var initZero = 0;

                $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
                    if (item.m4gs === "Completed") {
                        totalInActive++
                        if (item.Title in inactiveSet) {

                            inactiveSet[item.Title]++;
                        } else {
                            inactiveSet[item.Title] = 1;
                            activeSet[item.Title] = initZero;
                            otherSet[item.Title] = initZero;
                        }
                    } else if (item.m4gs === "Active") {

                        totalActive++
                        if (item.Title in activeSet) {

                            activeSet[item.Title]++;

                        } else {
                            inactiveSet[item.Title] = initZero;
                            activeSet[item.Title] = 1;
                            otherSet[item.Title] = initZero;
                        }
                    } else {
                        totalOther++
                        if (item.Title in otherSet) {
                            otherSet[item.Title]++;
                        } else {
                            inactiveSet[item.Title] = initZero;
                            activeSet[item.Title] = initZero;
                            otherSet[item.Title] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            var inactiveOrdered = {};
            var activeOrdered = {};
            var otherOrdered = {};

            Object.keys(activeSet).sort().forEach(function(key) {
                activeOrdered[key] = activeSet[key];
            });

            Object.keys(inactiveSet).sort().forEach(function(key) {
                inactiveOrdered[key] = inactiveSet[key];
            });

            Object.keys(otherSet).sort().forEach(function(key) {
                otherOrdered[key] = otherSet[key];
            });

            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

            var data = {
                labels: Object.keys(activeOrdered),
                datasets: [{
                        label: "Active",
                        fillColor: "steelblue",
                        data: Object.values(activeOrdered)
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Completed",
                        fillColor: "orange",
                        data: Object.values(inactiveOrdered)
                    }
                ]
            };
            ....    
</script>
```

The error is coming from the line starting with

```
...
var data = {
            labels: Object.keys(activeOrdered),
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is occurring because, **`Object.values()`** is not supported in Internet Explorer.

see [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility) for `Object.values()`

Here is a workaround, that you could use instead ...

```
data: Object.keys(activeOrdered).map(function(key) {return activeOrdered[key];})
```

and ...

```
data: Object.keys(inactiveOrdered).map(function(key) {return inactiveOrdered[key];})
```

Comment: that did make the error go away, however this code still is not displaying in IE but is displaying in Chrome with that said when I use just `data: Object.keys(inactiveOrdered)` i have a blank graph in both browsers.

Comment: syntax error at line `data: Object.keys(activeOrdered).map(key => activeOrdered[key]);`... it seems ok i might just have to examine it to see where it is

Comment: bingo!!! I had to take off the `;` at the end of those statements. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great !!­­­­­­­­­